# What triggers a user to be removed from the Google Analytics Real-Time View?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I'm using GAI 3.15.

I have the following code in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and it works great.

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = -1;
GAI.sharedInstance.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kTrackingId];
```

I've added code for reporting scene swaps, and I can see them in my GA view. I've added `dispatch` calls after each scene swap, and as you can see I've disabled auto-dispatching.

When I use the Real-Time view, scene swaps are reported almost immediately. But when I abort my app, it takes a couple of minutes for the user to be removed.

My question is the following: To my knowledge, I've not added any code to end the session. How does GA detect that the user has disappeared? Is there some kind of background polling mechanism, even if I've set `dispatchInterval` to -1?

And a follow-up: How come it takes only a couple of seconds for the scene swaps to get updated, but minutes for removing the user of a terminated app?

Comment: Would love to know this too. We are trying to track a pageview for our ios widget. We are trying to kill the session when the widget leaves the view via kGAISessionControl https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions I thought this would remove a user from the realtime view, but it is not.